# Navbar не растягивается всю ширину экрана

Tags: css, веб-программирование, display

При вёрстке navbar'a столкнулся с проблемой, что он не растягивается во всю ширину экрана.

```
<style>
    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #6A6666;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 200px; margin-right: 200px; height: 50px;">
        <!-- JackHelper Logo -->
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/svg/JackHelper-Nav-Logo.svg' %}" width="150px" height="50px"></a>
        
        <!-- Menu -->
        <ul style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <a href="#" class="menu">задачи</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">проценки</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">статистика</a>
            <a href="#" class="menu">сотрудники</a>
        </ul>

        <ul style="margin-top: 6px;">
            <a class="search" href="{% url 'login' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/svg/Search-Button.svg' %}" width="50px" height="35px"></a>
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/svg/Profile-Button.svg' %}" width="50px" height="35px"></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Слева он обрезается и не доходит до края экрана, несмотря на то, что `width=100%`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уберите паддинги марджины на боди и задайте ему тоже 100%. body{padding:0; margin:0; width:100%}

Comment: Куда делся `left: 0;`?

Comment: Благодарю Вас,  помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте обнуление стилей, которые по умолчанию задает браузер.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```